# Batch - how to determine if a specific network adaptor is already set to DHCP?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, netsh

I'm using `netsh interface ipv4 set address name="Ethernet" dhcp>nul` to set a network adaptor to DHCP in a batch file. I'm then checking the `errorlevel` to ensure it worked. When testing, if I run the batch file without elevated privileges it returns an error level of 1. However, it also returns an error level of 1 if I run the batch file *with* elevated privileges, if the adaptor is already set to DHCP.

How can I detect whether the error is simply "already set to DHCP" or "insufficient privileges" or something else entirely? I had thought I could perhaps check if the adaptor is already set to DHCP before running the `netsh` command, but I can't work out a simple way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a partial answer. The command

`netsh interface ipv4 show config name="Local Area Connection 2"`

produces a report that starts like this:

```
Configuration for interface "Local Area Connection 2"
    DHCP enabled:                         Yes
    IP Address:                           192.168.1.11
```

If the only item in the report that can have a "Yes" or "No" answer is DHCP enabled, then it should be fairly straightforward to look for "Yes" and base the next step on the answer. My batch skills are very rusty, so I won't attempt to suggest sample code.